# TCP vs UDP in load balancing rule with Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

What is the difference between TCP vs UDP in the load balancing rule?

What if UDF in the red box below is selected?

[image]

Image above is from the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/manage-rules-how-to

Answer (score 1):

This can be either used for port swapping or if you need to use port forwarding to keep consistency on your incoming sessions and so on...

Please take a look to the following URL below:

***Load-balancing rules are used to specify a pool of backend resources to route traffic to, balancing the load across each instance. For example, a load balancer rule can route TCP packets on port 80 of the load balancer across a pool of web servers.*****

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-faqs